# Is there any quick way to make mesh "even"?

Tags: mesh, transforms, vertices, faces

Is there any quick way to make mesh "even"? I have created a scene with displaced plane. Afterwards i want to sculpt it a bit and find it difficult for some "steep" faces. The mesh in the [image]green circle is somewhat even and dense but the red one is just terrible and it is the exact piece of mesh i want to sculpt.

Comment: Have you tried to smooth the vertices? In Edit Mode press Ctrl+V-->Smooth Vertex. Then hold Shift+R to repeat the process untill the vertices are relaxed.

Comment: @PaulGonet I will be able to try it out tomorrow afternoon, even though I know this will rather push the shape towards sphere and I want to preserve what I got here